# Can this Binomial Coefficient be written differently?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I am learning crypto and came across two binomial coefficients which is scary and I would like to write them differently. I would like to either separate the two coefficients or get rid of the sum (and how is that possible?).

My goal is to simplify this as much as possible so I can work with it:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}\binom{n+i-1}{i} $$

Bonus: is there any way to change such term into a simple polynomial function?

Comment: These are central Delannoy numbers and they are at http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+3%2C+13%2C+63%2C+321%2C+1683%2C+8989%2C+48639%2C+265729&sort=&language=&go=Search

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use that $\binom{n+i-1}{i}=\binom{n+i-1}{n-1}$ and simplify the expressions

Comment: This will give me $$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}\binom{n+i-1}{n-1} $$
Do you mind elaborating more on how to get the sum out? :)

Comment: Expanding the binomials you can simplify many terms

Comment: I followed your advice and this is what I came up with. It only got more complicated :)
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}\binom{n+i-1}{i} $$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}\binom{n+i-1}{n-1} $$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{(n-1)!}{i!*(n-1-i)!} \dfrac{(n+i-1)!}{(n-1)!i!} $$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{(n+i-1)!}{i!*i!*(n-1-i)!} $$

Am I doing anything wrong?